# SystemVerilog Concatenation

Tags: concatenation, system-verilog

I want to use a concatenation to store only the bottom half of a multiplication, however it tells me that my syntax is incorrect

```
module ALU
(
  input  signed [15:0] InSrc,
  input  signed [15:0] InDest,
  output logic signed [15:0] OutDest
);

  always_comb
  begin
    OutDest = {InDest*InSrc}[15:0];
  end

endmodule
```

the exact error is Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at ALU.sv(181) near text: "[";  expecting ";". Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to concatenate, the behavior is a multiply, then take a slice.
Here are two ways to take a slice.
Both produce the same result.

```
module ALU
(
  input  signed [15:0] InSrc,
  input  signed [15:0] InDest,
  output logic signed [15:0] OutDest
);

  integer product;
  
  always_comb
  begin
  product = InDest * InSrc;
  //
  // OutDest = product[15:0];
  OutDest = product[0 +: 16];
  end

endmodule
```

A testbench:

```
module tb ();
  
  integer OutDest;
 
  initial
    begin
    #1;
    $display("Outdest = %0d",OutDest);
    end
  
  ALU
  ALU(
    .InSrc(-1),
    .InDest(2),
    .OutDest(OutDest)
  );
      
endmodule
```

Produces:

```
Outdest = -2
```

In 4 different simulators on EDA Playground.